# Resizing div based on device

Tags: html, css, mobile, width

So I'm having trouble getting my div to resize based on if it's a mobile (specifically smartphone) device. Now the mobile device I'm using is the iPhone7plus. So I'm not sure if the dimensions I have are for this device.

my original css (for desktop) is this:

```
div#allContent div#mainContent div#contentText {
  width:50%;
  /*other styles*/
}
```

So the text on the screen is on one half of the page and the signup form will be on the other half. Now when I view in my iPhone the drop down items from the form are too big and I can't see the text inside the drop down boxes. So I'm trying to get the width of the contentText div to be 100% then also the form div to be 100%.

I added this to the bottom of my css file

I've tried this first line to:

```
/*@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px) {
@media screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px) {
  div#allContent div#mainContent div#contentText {
    width:100%;
  }
  div#allContent div#mainContent div#signupContent {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Is it because I have a larger mobile device that it's not working? Should i increase the max values? I'm just learning mobile device support.

Comment: If you still see boxes with width of 50%, you're out of declared resolution (320-480px).

Answer (score 1):

Mobile device max-width can be 767 after that i pad and notepad device width   starts.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:767px) {
  //code comes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the media query syntax is  different in your code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

}
```

I hope this media query will work for iphone portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is a syntax or you are not selecting the target correctly, if you post your full code (**HTML and CSS**) we could be more helpful.

Regardless, you could use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of `*-device-width`.

I have created example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/eeQKvB), check it out it will help you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's in my syntax. I was searching for other solutions and found a snippet on jsriddle that works. So I'm gonna go over my code line by line and see what's happening lol

Comment: So I just cleared my history and cache from my phone and it works. That was very weird. Although I kept refreshing the page on my phone and retyping in the url. Guess there was something in my cache or cookies preventing it from working.